# Ошибки валидации html кода

Tags: html, html5, html-validation

Много ошибок на `<meta>`.
Например, ругается на `<meta charset="utf-8" />`

> Attribute charset not allowed on element meta at this point.

---

Ссылка на ошибки
https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=http%3A%2F%2Fbemot.ru%2F#l82c75

Comment: Уберите Яндекс.Метрику, она обязана находиться внизу перед `</body>`, а не вверху

Comment: И вообще для каждой ошибки в отдельности должен быть отдельный [mcve] в отдельном вопросе, иначе всё это дело закроют за несоответствие формату Stack Overflow

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо. Не придал значению, что метрика в <head>
Ошибка исчезла